# assigning an object's name taken from expression

Tags: python

I need to extract data from external source. I build a base clas with some structure. I need objects with type of myBase class but with a name which automatically describes how many times I iterate over the source. I build a class which stores this number and with a call method which returns the object I need. I can't find a way to have a string as the name for the object but automatically differ every time I build new object.
I simplified the code for this example:

```
class myBase:
    def __init__(self):
        iteratedValue = None

class myIterator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = 0
    def __call__(self, s):
        self.k += 1
        self.name = 'myData' + str(self.k)
        # create an object named myData1, myData2 ...
        self.name = myBase() 
        self.name.iteratedValue = s 
        print '%s name is %s for k = %i' % (self.name, self.name.iteratedValue, self.k)

        # return object named myData1 type of myBase
        return self.name

def DataExtraction():
    # function to extract data form external source
    data = myIterator()
    data('Alice') 
    data('Ben') 

DataExtraction()
```

My output is:

```
<__main__.myBase instance at 0x7f261b6dc6c8> name is Alice for k = 1
<__main__.myBase instance at 0x7f261b6dc6c8> name is Ben for k = 2
```

I need to return an object with a specific name and I expect an output:

```
myData1 name is Alice for k = 1
myData2 name is Ben for k = 2
```

The original problem is much more complicated. I have external data and every time they come I want to extract some values from this data. Every time I am doing this I need an object to work with it but I need this object with different names because on the end I store them in dict for another methods. In other words I work with data and store my results in the object `myData1` when the original data change I work with it again and store the results in `myData2` etc. After all I need all `myData` objects and do statistics on them to see how the change. I do not have access to original data any more. I need automatic name convention for `myData` and the best if it will express iterator.

How can I have a string in place of `self.name` as the name for an object?

Comment: Note: If you are using properties, make sure your class derives (object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already doing it with `self.name = 'myData' + str(self.k)`.  The problem is that you immediately overwrite it with `self.name = myBase()`.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that `myBase()`, but you probably want to separate it from the name.  `self.name` can be either a string or a `myBase` object, but it can't be both.

Perhaps you can do:

```
    self.name = 'myData' + str(self.k)
    self.base= myBase() 
    self.base.iteratedValue = s 
    print '%s name is %s for k = %i' % (self.name, self.baseiteratedValue, self.k)
```

This way you can have both the name and the "base", as separate attributes `self.name` and `self.base`.

Alternatively, you can give the `myBase` class a `__str__` method.  This will affect what shows up when you use `print` on a `myBase` object.  However, to do that you'll have to pass in the desired name when you instantiate `myBase`, something like:

```
class myBase(object):
    def __init__(self, name, iteratedValue):
        self.name = name
        iteratedValue = iteratedValue
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class myIterator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = 0
    def __call__(self, s):
        self.k += 1
        name = 'myData' + str(self.k)
        self.name = myBase(name, s) 
        print '%s name is %s for k = %i' % (self.name, self.name.iteratedValue, self.k)

        # return object named myData1 type of myBase
        return self.name
```

I'm not sure which of these ways (or perhaps some other way) is what you're looking for.  What's puzzling is that you are making the "name" of the object be a `myBase` instance.  I'm not sure what you're intending the "name" of your object to represent, but I wouldn't usually expect an object's name to be some other object.

Incidentally, it looks like you're using Python 2, in which case you should define your class with `class someClass(object)`.  Including the `object` makes your classes new-style classes, which is basically what you always want.

Edit: If what you're trying to do is actually create a variable called `myData1` based on the string, so you can do `myData('Alice')` and then somehow magically have the variable `myData1` refer to that object, the answer is "Don't do that."  If you want to create a bunch of objects and access them in a structured way by numbers or other labels, use a list or a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn I know I override, I wanted to show what I try. I need to have an object `myData1` type of `myBase`, `myData2` type of `myBase` the problem is that I don't know how to get the name what I need and assign it to the object. I hope to return it from `call` method as `myData1 = myBase('Alice')` after next call `myData2 = myBase('Ben')` This example is simplify and in every iteration I have a lot of data in my object.

Comment: @Mus: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, but see my edited answer.  If you're trying to programmatically create variables with certain names, you can't and shouldn't do that.  Instead use a dictionary or list to access your objects.  If that's not what you mean, you'll need to give a specific example of what you're trying to do and how it fails.

Comment: @BrenBarn, you are wrong you can create variables with certain names `globals` and `locals`, however you're right in saying that you shouldn't

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you would be better off using generators. Here's some example code that reads data (actually it's hard-coded like in your example), and then construct Datum objects with the indexed name.

```
class Datum(object):
    def __init__(self, index, value):
        self.name = 'myData%d' % (index + 1)
        self.value = value

def read_data():
    yield 'Alice'
    yield 'Ben'

def enumerate_data():
    for i, value in enumerate(read_data()):
        yield Datum(i, value)

for d in enumerate_data():
    print d.name, d.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why worry about naming your objects at all, why not just put them in a `dict`?

```
myObjects = {1:Alice(), 2:Bob()}
```

Comment: The original problem is much more complicated. I have external data and every time they come I want to extract some values from this data. Every time I am doing this I need an object to work with it but I need this object with different names because on the end I store them in `dict` for another methods